# How to store some SQL code in DB2

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I have some SQL code, they are basically apply some transformation and do not take any parameter or ...here is a example of this queries

```
CREATE TABLE RESULT.R AS(
SELECT 
DISTINCT INVOICE, VOLUME, SUBCODE
FROM
(SELECT
    *
FROM
    Table 1
WHERE
    code= '1') AS TB
JOIN
(SELECT
    *
FROM
    Table2
WHERE 
    IND_STATUS_TYPE IS NULL
    AND
    type != 'Error' 
    AND
    STATUSCODE = '153'
)
ON
...
```

--UPDATES--

This transformation code depends on a couple of other transformations that need to be executed before it and create `Table 1` and `Table 2`. What is the best way to store these codes in the db2 so everyone accessing the database can access it and be able to run that

Comment: Create a view...

Answer (score 1):

You want a view. You can read more about a view from the [DB2 documentation here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/c0004106.html).

> A view provides a different way of looking at the data in one or more
>   tables; it is a named specification of a result table. The
>   specification is a SELECT statement that is run whenever the view is
>   referenced in an SQL statement. A view has columns and rows just like
>   a table. All views can be used just like tables for data retrieval.

Comment: Also, if you want  "everyone accessing the database can access it", you will need to grant select on the view to everyone. E.g.  `GRANT SELECT ON yourview TO PUBLIC`

Comment: Something I forgot to mention is, the final transformation code depends on a bunch of other intermediary transformation that need to run first. i.e. 2,3 pieces of code need to be executed first and create a couple of temporary tables and then the final code can run. I can store the final code as a 'view' but how about the data  preparation codes that come before?

Comment: I updated my original question to reflect this issue.

Comment: @H.Z. take a look at Common Table Expressions (CTEs), that may get you what you want: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/apsg/src/tpc/db2z_createcte.html

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an SQL PL stored procedure to store such logic inside the database? 
The stored procedure can return a result-set , or not, as you choose (or multiple result sets).

To invoke the logic, just CALL the stored-procedure, and you can grant EXECUTE on that procedure to specific roles or users/groups.

You can also use table-functions to store code.

There are plenty of examples of SQL PL procedures in both the Db2 Knowledge Center and also in the DB2 LUW installation folder in the samples directory tree.

Comment: so you're recommending to create one SP for each transformation? Can I have 'CREATE TABLE' statement in a SP?

Comment: SQL PL procedures can use dynamic-SQL to run DDL (such as create table).  They can contain multiple transformations. They can contain multiple units of work if required. They can have error detection and recovery, and procedural logic.  You need to *study* the examples supplied by IBM with your Db2-LUW.  *That* is my recommendation.